Swift performing task in parallel and showing progress
I have the following code
func randomIndices(n: Int) -> [Int] {
    var result: [Int] = []
    var used: [Bool] = (0 ..< n).map { _ in false }
    for _ in 0 ..< n {
        var r = Int.random(in: 0 ..< n)
        while used[r] {
            r = (r + 1) % n
        }
        used[r] = true
        result.append(r)
    }
    return result
}

func split<R>(array: [R], n: Int) -> [[R]] {
    var result: [[R]] = (0 ..< n).map { _ in [] }
    var index = 0
    for item in array {
        result[index].append(item)
        index = (index + 1) % n
    }
    return result
}

func inParallell<R>(count: Int, n: Int = 4, function: (Int) -> R, progress: ((Double) -> Void)? = nil) -> [R] {
    
    let indices = split(array: randomIndices(n: count), n: n)
    var res: [R?] = .init(repeating: nil, count: count)
    
    let lock = NSRecursiveLock()
    var meter = 0.0, step = 1.0 / Double(count)
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: indices.count) { i in
        for index in indices[i] {
            let result = function(index)
            lock.lock()
            res[index] = result
            meter += 1.0 / step
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("inParallell meter \(meter)")
                progress?(meter)
            }
            lock.unlock()
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        progress?(1)
    }
    return res.map({ $0! })
}

func waitSomeTime() {
    var x = 0
    for i in 0 ..< 1_000_000 {
        x += i
    }
}
struct InParallellTestView: View {
    @State var progress = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        ProgressView(value: progress)
            .onAppear {
                let _ = inParallell(count: 10, function: { _ in
                    waitSomeTime()
                }, progress: { p in progress = p })
            }
    }
}

The idea is that the progress bar should be updated while the code runs, but if I look at the printout it says "inParallell meter 100.0" repeated, ie all meter updates occur at the end. I've tried the whole ConcurrentPerform block in a "DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).sync" block but that dit not change the result.
I tried running the code and also changing the DispatchQueue.main.async to sync but that did not make a difference either. The result is that all updates to the progress bar occur after the computation is finished.

The key problems were that:

The concurrentPerform blocks the caller’s thread (the main thread). No UI updates can therefore happen while the calculation was underway.

Also, the meter calculation was incorrect, not returning values outside of 0 ... 1.

The waitSomeTime didn’t return anything, so there was nothing to populate in the final results.



So, going into a little more detail:

One significant problem is that concurrentPerform blocks the caller‘s thread. Typically we would dispatch that to a global queue, to avoid blocking the main thread. And if we do this all asynchronously on a background thread, you cannot just return the result, but you need to provide another completion handler for completion.

Also, if you print your progress values, they are not between 0 and 1 (because the incrementing of meter was incorrect). I have updated these calculations below.

As a minor point, the use of the lock is problematic:

One should use a NSLock (or OSAllocatedUnfairLock), not NSRecursiveLock. Use of NSRecursiveLock is generally code-smell for sloppy lock code. It is just not needed here.

I would advise avoiding manually lock and unlock. Instead, use withlock, and tightly scope the update of the local variables with the lock. I then capture the updated meter to avoid races with the main thread, too.



I would, for illustrative purposes, make waitSomeTime take well defined period of time. Sometimes these calculations of adding a million values can go so quickly that it looks nearly instantaneous.
You also want it to return some result (so that it can be passed as the function parameter and whose calculation can be used to populate the final array of results). Because the original was not returning anything, the results were being populated with all nil values.
Anyway, in my demonstration, I refactored waitSomeTime to the following:
func computationallyIntensiveCalculation() -> Int {
    let start = ContinuousClock.now
    while start.duration(to: .now) < .seconds(1) {
        // this is intentionally blank; we’re spinning to simulate some computationally intensive task
    }
    return Int.random(in: 0..<100)
}

I’ve renamed from merely waitSomeTime to computationallyIntensiveCalculation to clarify that we’re simulating some computationally expensive routine that will return a value.

As a refinement, I might simplify randomIndices to merely (0..<n).shuffled().

Likewise, split is probably misnamed. The convention for “split” is a function that breaks one long sequence into into shorter subsequences. But that’s not what you’re doing here. You are distributing the sequence into separate buckets. That is not what most Swift programmers would understand as “split”. I might rename this to be distributed or something like that. Furthermore, I would simplify it and move it into an extension of Sequence:
extension Sequence {
    func distributed(into n: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        let buckets = [[Element]](repeating: [], count: n)

        return enumerated()
            .reduce(into: buckets) { (partialResult, tuple) in
                partialResult[tuple.0 % n].append(tuple.1) 
            }
    }
}

We could make that even more concise, but I wanted to make my intent as clear as possible.

You were collating the results into an array of nil values. Personally, I’d collect the results into an unordered structure (i.e., a dictionary) and then build the array at the end (of type [R], not [R?]). Or alternatively, you could stick with your pattern, but you still would want to compactMap the [R?] to [R].


So, instead, you might have something like:
import SwiftUI

extension Sequence {
    func distributed(into n: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        let buckets = [[Element]](repeating: [], count: n)
        
        return enumerated()
            .reduce(into: buckets) { (partialResult, tuple) in
                partialResult[tuple.0 % n].append(tuple.1) 
            }
    }
}

func computationallyIntensiveCalculation() -> Int {
    let start = ContinuousClock.now
    while start.duration(to: .now) < .seconds(1) {
        // this is intentionally blank; we’re spinning to simulate some computationally intensive task
    }
    return Int.random(in: 0..<100)                   // but let’s return _something_.
}

func inParallel<R>(
    count: Int,
    n: Int = 4,
    function: @escaping (Int) -> R,
    progress: ((Double) -> Void)? = nil,
    completion: @escaping ([R]) -> Void
) {
    let indexGroups = (0..<count).shuffled().distributed(into: n)
    var resultDictionary: [Int: R] = [:]
    
    let lock = NSLock()                              // not `NSRecursiveLock`
    var meter = 0.0
    let step = 1.0 / Double(count)
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: indexGroups.count) { i in
            for index in indexGroups[i] {
                let result = function(index)
                let meter = lock.withLock {
                    resultDictionary[index] = result
                    meter += step                    // not `1 / step`
                    return meter
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [meter] in
                    progress?(meter)
                }
            }
        }
        
        let sortedResults = (0..<count).compactMap { resultDictionary[$0] }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            progress?(1)
            completion(sortedResults)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var progress = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        ProgressView(value: progress)
            .onAppear {
                inParallel(count: 50) { _ in
                    computationallyIntensiveCalculation()
                } progress: { p in
                    print("progress", p)
                    progress = p 
                } completion: { result in
                    print("completion", result)
                }
            }
    }
}


For what it’s worth, I tried to stay with the GCD approach of your original question. But this, like your original example, does not support cancelation. I might be inclined to adopt Swift concurrency. For example:
import SwiftUI

func computationallyIntensiveCalculation() async throws -> Int {
    let start = ContinuousClock.now
    while start.duration(to: .now) < .seconds(1) {
        try Task.checkCancellation()                // periodically check for cancellation …
        await Task.yield()                          // … and yield
        
        // this is intentionally blank; we’re spinning to simulate some computationally intensive task
    }
    return Int.random(in: 0..<100)                  // but let’s return _something_.
}

@MainActor
class Calculation: ObservableObject {
    @Published var progress = 0.0
    
    func incrementProgress(by value: Double) {
        progress += value
        print(progress)
    }
    
    func inParallel<R: Sendable>(
        count: Int,
        n: Int = 4,
        function: @escaping @Sendable (Int) async throws -> R
    ) async throws -> [R] {
        let indexGroups = (0..<count).shuffled().distributed(into: n)
        
        let step = 1.0 / Double(count)
        
        return try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: [Int: R].self) { group in
            var resultDictionary: [Int: R] = [:]
            
            for indexGroup in indexGroups {    
                _ = group.addTaskUnlessCancelled(priority: .utility) {
                    var groupDictionary: [Int: R] = [:]
                    for index in indexGroup {
                        groupDictionary[index] = try await function(index)
                        await self.incrementProgress(by: step)
                    }
                    
                    return groupDictionary
                }
            }
            
            for try await dictionary in group {
                resultDictionary.merge(dictionary) { $1 } 
            }
            
            return (0..<count).compactMap { resultDictionary[$0] }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var calculation = Calculation()
    
    var body: some View {
        ProgressView(value: calculation.progress)
            .task {
                do {
                    let result = try await calculation.inParallel(count: 50) { _ in
                        try await computationallyIntensiveCalculation()
                    }
                    print(result)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    func distributed(into n: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        let buckets = [[Element]](repeating: [], count: n)
        
        return enumerated()
            .reduce(into: buckets) { (partialResult, tuple) in
                partialResult[tuple.0 % n].append(tuple.1) 
            }
    }
}

Unlike .onAppear, the .task view modifier will automatically cancel the Swift concurrency task when the view is dismissed. But for that to work, computationallyIntensiveCalculation needs to periodically checkCancelation. Likewise, you might want to periodically yield, too, to honor the Swift concurrency contract to not impede forward progress on a thread from the cooperative thread pool.
This is all beyond the scope of your original question, but the main point is that you might contemplate using Swift concurrency rather than GCD.

FWIW, the original question was (a) building a random array of indices and then (b) distributing them amongst groups of indices. This is a very curious pattern. It might not be relevant here, but often we would enjoy performance benefits by striding, with each thread tackling adjacent values (to minimize edge-case cache-sloshing). So, I’d encourage future readers to not dwell on the above “groups of random indices” pattern, and instead just appreciate (a) the avoidance of concurrentPerform from main thread and (b) the progress values within the appropriate range of 0 to 1.
